# What measure (if any) does HTTPS use to hide the request path length?

Tags: tls

I really, really thought I remembered seeing the existence of some standardized header or TLS packet whose purpose is to (try to) hide the **length** of the requested URL from an eavesdropper. But I cannot find anything about this at this time.

What — if any — measures does HTTPS use to decrease the eavesdropper's ability to guess the length of the requested path?

Comment: TLS supports [record padding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-5.4) to hide the length of the payload - although I don't know if TLS clients actually use it in practice. A client could also simply add nonsense fields to the HTTP header as a form of application level padding to hide the length of the relevant parts (including the URL) in the request.

Answer (score 35):

HTTPS / TLS does not try to hide the length of URL. If someone intercepts traffic, the only things that are visible are host, port and the volume of the traffic. It is impossible to know what this traffic contains. For instance, 10000 bytes traffic can mean a GET request where 9000 bytes are used by URL and 1000 bytes by cookies. Or it can be a POST request with a short URL of 50 bytes, 1000 bytes cookies and about 9000 bytes payload.

Comment: Would combining the cookies, payload and request-path into an incoherent blob not constitute an effort to hide the URL length (and the length of all the other bits and bobs)?

Comment: @Persistence not intentionally. Of course, the webapp itself (independently of the TLS layer) can vary the length randomly.

Comment: Or it could be another application transmitting data through TLS - it's not HTTPS at all.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that in addition to host and port, the domain name is typically visible via SNI.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude I interpreted "host and port" to be the TCP address, in which the host is actually just an IP address, not "host" in the same sense as the HTTP header by that name.  In this context that feels like the right interpretation, but I guess only the author of this answer could tell us for sure.

Comment: Is a 9000 byte URL even feasible? From a cursory search, it appears that once you get past around 2048 or so, you'll run into issues with search engines and IE, and around 8192, you get problems on Android and CDNs.

Comment: @Nzall: Sure it is feasible. It would be helpful, if you would provide links to the sources that support your statement about search and URL length. There were times when 2,048 was much. Static URLs are still relatively short. But static URLs are only a one of possible usages. Now days there are a lot of web and mobile applications that communicate with their backends over HTTPS. Many of them transfer data not, or not only, as a payload in POST, PUT, PATCH requests, but in the URLs. Google Chrome supports URL length of 2,097,152 characters, Firefox 65,536 characters, Safari 80,000 characters.

Comment: @Nzall: This is down to implementation quality. The client can send whatever it wants, and the server can either accept it or respond with HTTP 414 URI Too Long. A server could be implemented to fail at 200 bytes, or even less, but I should like to believe that common implementations are more robust than that.

Comment: @AaronDufour TLSv1.3 allows SNI to be sent as an encrypted extension which is one of many reasons TLSv1.3 is preferred over previous versions.

Comment: @AaronDufour Alas, the edit [clarifying that](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/179939) was rolled-back...

Answer (score 1):

The other answer already explains that it is really the size of the request header that matters.  [TLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-5.4) allows padding to be added.  And so does [HTTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-6.1).  Since HTTP/2, the data frame which is used to send requests can have padding.  The use of padding is discussed in Chapter 10.7.  Just read the specs.  Even without access to these facilities, say AJAX in a browser, the script can simply pad the request path or body to a set length.